# Can't get changed entities after SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to do some loggings after data successfully changed. I am using entity framework core for that purpose. There is `SavingChanges` event handler that is called BEFORE saving changes to DB and there is `SavedChanges` event handler that is called AFTER saving changes. In `SavingChanges` I can get modified entities by using `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` and select entities with changed state `context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)`, but in `SavedChanges` event all entries are showing unchanged even though I have 3 changed entities. Can someone suggest good solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once they’ve been saved, they’re now `unchanged` as they represent the current state of the DB for those entities.  Record which entities were modified/added/deleted in `SavingChanges` then use this information in `SavedChanges` to do whatever you need done with them.

Comment: Yeah, I think this would work, but I also think of writing custom context and overriding `SavaChangesAsync()` method so that all the logics will be inside class.

Comment: Also can you suggest where to keep that info, because when I go from one event to another data is getting lost

Comment: You should abstract the operations into its own class that supports the two operations you’re looking for - recording changes, then providing those changes in a useful format.  Then  another class should be designed to take that info and perform your logging

Comment: Yes, I had a problem because of immutability of entity's select object, but converting to list fixed the issue. Thank you ! ))